# Cannot apply tensorflow model in OpenCV

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv

Hello I have problem with applying tensorflow model in OpenCV. The code below properly load model, but when calling forward method Assertion error is thrown. Do you have any ideas where is the problem? Or how to debug/find it?

```
cv::dnn::Net net;
string path;
path = "graph.pb";
net = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(path);
if (net.empty())
{
    std::cerr << "Can't load network by using the given files." << std::endl;
    return ;
}
Mat image = imread(imagePath)
Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(image, 1.0, Size(512, 512), Scalar(0,0,0), true, false);
int N = inputBlob.size[0], C = inputBlob.size[1], H = inputBlob.size[2], W = inputBlob.size[3]; // [1, 3, 512, 512]
net.setInput(inputBlob);        //set the network input
Mat output = net.forward(); // <- throws error
```

**Error**:

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Workspace\ImageAnalysisPlus\x64\Debug\opencv_world3410d.dll File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector Line: 1789

Expression: back() called on empty vector

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

---

OpenCV version: 4.4.0

Tensorflow model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aE0smAw-CyPLch6UY8blK3RreT5RrZfN/view?usp=sharing

Platform: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017

I tried to load the model in python and OpenCV and it works.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: I just tried your code and model on Ubuntu 18.04 and OpenCV 4.2.0 I have no problems loading and forwarding the model. It might be due to the OpenCV version although the 4.4.0 seems to me more robust to external graphs than the previous one. Same issue here that has been resolved by changing the model but it's probably not what you want to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit that I didn't try the posted minimal code. It was part of a little bigger code. The minimal code works also on my machine. Knowing that I found out that I was **calling the forward method on uninitialized network** which caused the error. I initialized local net variable in init method in a class instead of a class attribute.